# How to add a cookie to CookieContainer with commas in its value c#

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I have to send a request with an authentication cookie to a site I don't control. The problem is that the cookie has commas in its value (I use EditThisCookie to get cookie value). 
I get this exception :"part of the cookie is invalid." because commas should be seperators.
What do I do in this situation? I have to send the cookie with commas but .Net gives me an exception.
I need it to ignore the commas. Just send the request. 
Also I have seen many answers on stackoverflow and other sites saying I should use **UrlEncode** but that would only work if the server would decode the cookie but that won't happen since I have no control over the server,right? Well it didn't work for me anyway.
*Code:*

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie();
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Secure = true;
        cookie.Name = "token";
        cookie.Value = "65711831-97d3-41c9-a9dd-3fbc7a7a14fc,212823c191e8ea561b13e6d07a1dbf3a,uVKJHhoDBGPP/s96tmbuyTvCSw0HiaRykXGFmCL4YJnGaDz1E7fNFo/"; // This is a part of the value
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        cookies.Add(new Uri("https://www.lynda.com/"), cookie);
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
```

Comment: Did you try url encoding? Did it work?

Comment: Commas are not allowed values in cookies.

Comment: No url encoding didn't work since the site which I have no control over won't decode it so it reads %2c literally and not as ","

Comment: Also I know that commas aren't allowed but this site uses them in its authentication cookie and it works. This site is a popular site ,too.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Cookie_Value -- "The Value of a Cookie must not be null. If a null value is assigned to this property, it's replaced with an empty string.

Semicolons and commas are reserved characters that cannot be used in the value of this property. Assigning invalid characters to this property doesn't throw an exception; but when you try to add this Cookie to a CookieContainer instance with the Add method, the operation will fail and throw an exception."

Comment: So I guess my suggestion is to not use the CookieContainer and Cookie class and figure out a way to roll your own with basic http request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is comma is a valid separator for cookie values. Try setting the comma using url-encoding `%2C` for comma instead of the comma character.

For example `abc%2Cde` instead of `abc,de`